# Cannot find parent aspect for concrete aspect

Tags: java, maven-plugin, aspectj, wildfly-8, load-time-weaving

I have trying to test load time weaving in simple hello world normal Servlet based example in wildfly8.2

I have below Aspect code

```
package com.test.aspects;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

import com.test.helloworld.HelloService;

@Aspect
public abstract class FieldAspect {

    @Pointcut
    public abstract void getField();

    @Pointcut
    public abstract void setField();

    @Around("getField()")
    public HelloService getFieldValue() {
        System.out.println("In FieldAspect.getFieldValue() - Applying around advice - getting the value (Andy) for field annotated variable");
        return new HelloService();
    }

    @Around("setField()")
    public void setFieldValue() {
        System.out
                .println("In FieldAspect.setFieldValue() - Applying around advice - throw RuntimeException if field annotated variable is set");
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

The below run time field annotation

```
package com.test.aspects;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Field {

}
```

Test Servlet:

```
package com.test.helloworld;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.test.aspects.Field;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

    static String PAGE_HEADER = "<html><head><title>helloworld</title></head><body>";

    static String PAGE_FOOTER = "</body></html>";

   @Field
   public  HelloService helloService;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.println(PAGE_HEADER);
        writer.println("<h1>" + helloService.createHelloMessage("World") + "</h1>");
        writer.println(PAGE_FOOTER);
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

Service class:

```
package com.test.helloworld;

public class HelloService {

    String createHelloMessage(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }

}
```

Aop.xml under web-inf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aspectj>
    <aspects>

        <!-- Field annotation example -->
        <concrete-aspect name="com.test.aspects.MyFieldAspect"
            extends="com.test.aspects.FieldAspect">
            <pointcut name="getField" expression="get(@com.test.aspects.Field * *)" />
            <pointcut name="setField" expression="set(@com.test.aspects.Field * *)" />
        </concrete-aspect>


    </aspects>

    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo" />
</aspectj>
```

And the POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.wildfly.quickstarts</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>WildFly : Helloworld</name>
    <description>WildFly : Helloworld</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>


        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>

        <version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0>1.0.0.Final</version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0>


        <!-- other plugin versions -->
        <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>2.1.1</version.war.plugin>

        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Define the version of JBoss' Java EE 7 APIs we want to use -->
            <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 7 APIs including
                a Bill of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or
                a collection) of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct
                versions of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-7.0 stack (you can
                read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs). You can actually
                use this stack with any version of WildFly that implements Java EE 7, not
                just WildFly 8! -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>            
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
            as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Servlet API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Set the name of the war, used as the context root when the app 
            is deployed -->
        <finalName>wildfly-helloworld</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-compiler-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [2.5.1,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.codehaus.mojo
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            aspectj-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.7,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Java EE 7 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- WildFly plugin to deploy war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
                    <jvmArgs>${the-whole-jvm-args}</jvmArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Compiler plugin enforces Java 1.6 compatibility and activates 
                annotation processors -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Used below link to configure the Load time weaving: `http://wiki.eclipse.org/LTWJboss7`

So after above if I  start wildfly, it shows below error stack trace.

```
[AppClassLoader@1912a56] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.5 built on Thursday Jan 29, 2015 at 01:03:58 GMT
[AppClassLoader@1912a56] info register classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1912a56
[AppClassLoader@1912a56] info using configuration file:/helloworld/target/wildfly-helloworld.war!/WEB-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@1912a56] info define aspect com.test.aspects.MyFieldAspect
[AppClassLoader@1912a56] error Cannot find parent aspect for: <concrete-aspect name='com.test.aspects.MyFieldAspect' extends='com.test.aspects.FieldAspect' perclause='null'/> in aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@1912a56] error Concrete-aspect 'com.test.aspects.MyFieldAspect' could not be registered
[AppClassLoader@1912a56] warning failure(s) registering aspects. Disabling weaver for class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1912a56
```

I am confused here what has been done wrong. Can someone help me to run my test program. I am learning AspectJ and LTW with wildfly and new to this all.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

classpath was wrong.
Place the aspectjWeaver jar in WEB-INF/lib folder.
Also package aop module as create Aspects inside war module , create aspects in different module and package in jar.

Comment: You can either accept your own question in order to close it or just delete it altogether if you prefer because all the specified information was unrelated to your problem.

Comment: May you help me to correct my answer as the error error "Cannot find parent aspect for: <concrete-aspect name='com.test.aspects.MyFieldAspect' extends='com.test.aspects.FieldAspect' perclause='null'/>" in aop.xm was occurred as aspects com.test.aspects.FieldAspect was not found in classpath and the same i found during debugging the aspectjweaver code: BcelWorld.resolve() routine. The reason was i must not put my aop.xml in war as in was aspect classpath was not found.

Comment: though its my solution which i applied and worked ,so i close it by accepting it :) n thnx if you suggest me to correct my phrases in more technical depth.